# Calculating Angle/Curvature?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to apply the Gauss-Bonnet theorem to my C++ OpenGL application and compute the value of the interior angle at vertex Vi in the neighboring triangle Fi in my mesh.

I did some searching before making this post, and I know that to do this for a 2D model, one could use the function below to get the angles:

```
void angles(double points[][2], double angles[], int npoints){
for(int i = 0; i < npoints; i++){
    int last = (i - 1 + npoints) % npoints;
    int next = (i + 1) % npoints;
    double x1 = points[i][0] - points[last][0];
    double y1 = points[i][1] - points[last][1];
    double x2 = points[next][0] - points[i][0];
    double y2 = points[next][1] - points[i][1];
    double theta1 = atan2(y1, x1)*180/3.1415926358979323;
    double theta2 = atan2(y2, x2)*180/3.1415926358979323;
    angles[i] = (180 + theta1 - theta2 + 360);
    while(angles[i]>360)angles[i]-=360;
} }
```

But how can I find the angles with a 3D mesh (x, y, and z) vertices?

Answer (score 0):

The analogous concept in 3D is called *Gaussian curvature*. The situation is much more complicated than 2D, and there is no single good way of calculating or estimating the Gaussian curvature for a mesh. There's a [survey paper](http://www.ijesit.com/Volume%202/Issue%203/IJESIT201303_48.pdf) that may give you some ideas.